# how to write Junit test case for testing duplicate elements count in string

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How to write junit test case to test the duplicate value count in given string  my code is below can some one help me please

### Original

```
public void countDupChars(String str) {

        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

        for (Character ch : chars) {
            if (map.containsKey(ch)) {
                map.put(ch, map.get(ch) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(ch, 1);
            }
        }

        Set<Character> keys = map.keySet();
        for (Character ch : keys) {
            if (map.get(ch) > 1) {
                System.out.println("Char " + ch + " " + map.get(ch));
            }
        }
    }
```

### Test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestMessageBuilder {

    @InjectMocks
    MessageBuilder builder;

    @Test
    public void testfindcountDupChars() {
        doReturn(true).when(builder).countDupChars("Ramakrishna");
        verify(builder, times(1)).countDupChars("Ramakrishna");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to use a mock library at all. In you code it looks like you are mocking the object that should actually been tested (`MessageBuilder`). I would recommend to change the signature of the `countDupChars` method and return the map of found duplicates.

E.g.:

```
public Map<Character, Integer> countDupChars(String str) {

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

    for (Character ch : chars) {
        if (map.containsKey(ch)) {
            map.put(ch, map.get(ch) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(ch, 1);
        }
    }

    Set<Character> keys = map.keySet();
    for (Character ch : keys) {
        if (map.get(ch) > 1) {
            System.out.println("Char " + ch + " " + map.get(ch));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

In the test you can then simply asset the returned map (assuming `countDupChars` is a method of the `MessageBuilder` class).

```
public class TestMessageBuilder {

    MessageBuilder builder = new MessageBuilder();

    @Test
    public void testfindcountDupChars() {
        Map<Character, Integer> result = builder.countDupChars("Ramakrishna");
        Assert.assertSame(result.get('R'), 1);
        Assert.assertSame(result.get('a'), 3);
        Assert.assertSame(result.get('m'), 1);
        // and so on ...
    }
}
```